# Does anyone know about this IC/chip from and RC helicopter?

Tags: integrated-circuit, remote-control

I have an RC helicopter toy (FastLane RC Pro Flight Helicopter) which I had to disassemble for fixing.

I have a chip/IC on the pcb board of that helicopter. On the chip it says 103FMTB11.

[image: 103FMTB11]

I would appreciate if someone would provide datasheet or any type of information.
Or any smd code book that provides the information which I couldn't find so far anything about it.

Thanks,

Comment: You're really unlikely to ever find out what that IC is.

Comment: Why not? I don't know why you are saying that?

Comment: It's just the way things are. Being in a cheap mass-produced product greatly increases the chances it's an insider IC only known by and provided to companies that buy them in the tens of thousands to build things with. Sometimes specifically made for that product and nothing else. In that case even if the label was the part number you're still out of luck. And on top of that, it doesn't help that those labels are often not even the part numbers of but some other proprietary information (like a lot number).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.